# Elmah - How does it create partition key in Azure table storage

Tags: elmah

We're using Elmah to log errors to an azure storage table. The volume of data is now quite large and requires some clean up.

Querying the data by time stamp is not efficient.

I'm wondering how does Elmah create the partition key for entries and if I could use that to start clearing down data - if it is logically sequenced on some incremental basis ?

Comment: This might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397994/pass-the-elmah-error-sequence-number-not-guid-for-the-exception-to-custom-erro)

Comment: thanks Milana - thats more related to storing data in SQL server . We're using Azure Tables .  But a useful hint in there around checking out the source code , which I hadn't thought of.